# Bash regex for same sender and receiver with backreference

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I try to make a regex (important that ist a regex because i need it for fail2ban) to match when
the receiver and the sender are the same person:

```
echo "from=<test@test.ch>    to=<test@test.ch>" | grep -E -o  '([^=]*\s)[ ]*\1'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You could use a backreference `from=<([^\s@<>]+@[^\s@<>]+)>\s*to=<\1>` and if supported the `grep -oP` option https://regex101.com/r/V18mbR/1 like `echo "from=<test@test.ch>    to=<test@test.ch>" | grep -oP  'from=<([^\s@<>]+@[^\s@<>]+)>\s*to=<\1>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a pattern to match the format of the string between the brackets with a backreference to that capture.

```
from(=<[^\s@<>]+@[^\s@<>]+>)\s*to\1
```

**Explanation**

- `from` Match literally
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `=<` Match literally
  - `[^\s@<>]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or `@` `<` `>`
  - `@` Match literally
  - `[^\s@<>]+` Again match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or `@` `<` `>`
  - `>` Match literally
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s*to\1` Match 0+ whitespace chars, `to` and the backreference to group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ANO7TC/1) | [Bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BKa0oP9fWpiS1uMQBROglZ9gpAEFJPpqgkkKNQnpRaoGCbn6AgoI6SJuGrU10XEyxg41drLYDnGWnGVOsVZIfY6j@/z8A)

Use `grep -P` instead of `-E` for Perl compatible regular expressions.

For example

```
echo "from=<test@test.ch>    to=<test@test.ch>" | grep -oP  'from(=<[^\s@<>]+@[^\s@<>]+>)\s*to\1'
```

A bit broader match could be capturing what is between the brackets

```
[^=\s]+(=<[^<>]+>)\s*[^=\s]+\1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqC585/1)

Comment: Can the first regex be simplified to `grep -oP 'from(=<[^>]+>)\s*to\1' ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes that is also possible, see https://regex101.com/r/PIUhh7/1 It depends on how specific you want the match to be.